# Storyboard & Segue - Passing datas am i doing it good?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I'm using Storyboards & segues. I want to switch from "Contacts List" (tableView) to a "Profile view" (ScrollView).

**Three questions** :

- Is this the best way (more clean & beautiful) to do this ? **& Why ?**
- When i do this : ProfileViewController *aProfileView = (ProfileViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]; is this instantiate a new view ? (Like it will create 2 Profile view).
- do i need to clean (delete the "Profile View" somewhere ?) or it's doing it alone with the Navigation controller ?

// Code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showProfileSelected"]) 
    {
        // Get the Selected raw
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Profile *selectedProfile = [self.profilesTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Using segue --> Send the current selected profile to "ProfileView"
        ProfileViewController *aProfileView = (ProfileViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        aProfileView.currentProfile = selectedProfile;
    }
}
```

// Other way to do this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showProfileSelected"]) 
    {
        // Get the Selected raw
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Profile *selectedProfile = [self.profilesTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Using segue --> Send the current selected profile to "ProfileView"
        [segue.destinationViewController setCurrentProfile:selectedProfile];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is fine. You aren't creating anything, just getting a reference to your destination controller. Setting up a variable like that allows you to set multiple properties on the destination view controller without having to cast over and over again.

So, to answer your specific questions:

- yes, that's the best way. It's difficult to get prepareForSegue "beautiful" because of the generic class of destination view controller
- no, you're not creating anything.
- no, you don't have anything to clean up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is this necessary ? (ProfileViewController *) because it's also working without that.

Comment: You're probably getting a compiler warning, though? What you're doing there is called a cast, and it let's the compiler know what class it is dealing with (e.g a ProfileViewController, not a UIViewController)

Comment: No, i'm not getting any compiler warning - i wasn't sure that is a cast. Thanks again for that